# Is there an indexOf equivalent for arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm brand new to C and hope there's something built in that I can use.  Say I have a list and I want to find the location of a list(all items in the lists are unique). Like so:
`char *name[] =  {"monkey", "pig", "goat", "dog", "cat"};` I tried:

```
   char *name[] =  {"monkey", "pig", "goat", "dog", "cat"};
   int *found = strstr (*name,"dog");
   printf("Found at %i \n", found); //expect 3(or 4, if it doesn't use 0s) result
```

but it keeps giving me the result of 2(even if I put names that don't exist). I swapped `strstr` with `strcspn` with no luck either.

I am asking because I wasn't sure and I created my own function to do this but its pretty crappy and not very flexible(I hardcode the list name in it), I figured if there's something within C then it'll be better for me. Here's the function I made(cover your eyes if you don't want to lose brain cells reading it, joking :-):

```
int indexOf(char nameToFind) {
    //returns the location of an item in a list
    int pos = -1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(name) / sizeof(name[0]) && pos == -1; i++)
    {
        // Assuming there is a char[] field called name in Stdinfo
        if (*name[i] == nameToFind) {
            pos = i;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

Does something like this exist in C that would be faster & more flexible than my version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code your wrote is wrong on a few levels.  Your line

```
char *name[] = {"monkey", "pig", "goat", "dog", "cat"};
```

creates an array of `char` pointers, each pointing to a `NULL`-terminated string.  So far, so good.  However, your line

```
int *found = strstr (*name,"dog");
```

sets `found` to a pointer to the first occurrence of `"dog"` in `*name = name[0] = "monkey"`.  Besides not looking through the array `name` as you intend, you're also assigning the `char *` returned by `strstr` to an `int *`.  Not good.  Your next line

```
printf("Found at %i \n", found);
```

tries to print `found`, but the specifier requires an `int` and you're passing it `found`, an `int *`.  These are all things to avoid, and I think a lot of this is undefined behavior.

What you want is a loop that uses `strcmp`, for example:

```
char *name[] = {"monkey", "pig", "goat", "dog", "cat"};
unsigned int numElements = sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0]);
unsigned int i;
for(i = 0; i < numElements; ++i) {
    if (strcmp(name[i], "dog") == 0) {
        printf("Found at %u\n", i);
        break;
    }
}
if (i >= numElements) {
    printf("Not found\n");
}
```

Computing `numElements` in this way won't work if you pass the array into a function, so you'll have to explicitly pass the number of elements in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining my mistakes. I'll change my code around thanks.  But I don't understand why use `if (strcmp(name[i], "dog") == 0) {` if I'm looping through all the elements can't I simply just do what I'm doing in my function and do something like if (name[i] == "dog") { ...

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  `name[i]` is a `char *`, some address in memory.  At that address is some `NULL`-terminated string (hopefully), but the comparison just looks at that address.  Similarly, `"dog"` is an address in memory, the bytes starting there spelling out `dog` followed by a `NULL` byte.  Thus, you'd just be checking if two addresses are the same, not if there are equal strings beginning at them.

Comment: Two string literals "dog" are likely to yield the same address, as the compiler will generally try to ensure it doesn't store repeated string literals multiple times in the executable image.  But, if the text "dog" is generated at run time in a character buffer - perhaps read from the keyboard, file, or the network - the program will need a separate memory area to store the string that might or might not be "dog" for later comparison.  In that case, `strcmp()` will correctly compare the contents and not just the address.

Answer (score 1):

For character arrays, there is the [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr) function, which searches an array for a character.  If it finds it, it returns a pointer to that character.  If not, it will return a NULL pointer.  You can then use pointer subtraction to determine the index.

For general arrays, there is the library [`bsearch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/bsearch) function if the array is sorted.  Most compilers provide an [`lsearch`](http://praxis.edoceo.com/man/3/LSEARCH) nonstandard function that just does a linear search over the array to find a given value.

If you are using C++, then you have access to the `find`, `lower_bound`, and `upper_bound` STL algorithms, which perform similar tasks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did spend some time search strchr earlier and all the examples have things like char name[] = {"Hello world"}; and then they look for the word `world`. When I try to modify it for my data get null. Am I correct to be expecting a char and then subtract it from the total size of the array?  Also, I'm just using pure c(no c++)